# Deployment invalid: spec.template.metadata.labels: Invalid value

Tags: deployment, kubernetes

Deploying my service to production:

```
envsubst < ./kubernetes/pre-production/aks.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

I'm getting the following error:

> The Deployment "moverick-mule-pre" is invalid:
>   spec.template.metadata.labels: Invalid value:
>   map[string]string{"commit":"750a26deebc3582bec4bfbb2426b3f22ee042eaa",
>   "app":"moverick-mule-pre"}: `selector` does not match template
>   `labels`

My yaml file is:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: moverick-mule-pre
spec:
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: moverick-mule-pre
        commit: $CI_COMMIT_SHA
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: moverick-mule-pre
        image: $REGISTRY_SERVER_PRE/$CI_PROJECT_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        envFrom:
          - secretRef:
              name: moverick-pre
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /console
            port: 80
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 5
        volumeMounts:
        - name: logs
          mountPath: /opt/mule/logs/
        - name: asc
          mountPath: /opt/mule/asc/
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: registry-pre
      volumes:
      - name: logs
        azureFile:
          secretName: azure-files-pre
          shareName: logs-pre
          readOnly: false
      - name: asc
        azureFile:
          secretName: azure-asc-pre
          shareName: asc-pre
          readOnly: false
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: moverick-mule-pre
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: moverick-mule-pre
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You need to add `selector` in `spec` of Deployment.

And also, these `selector` should match with `labels` in PodTemplate.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: moverick-mule-pre
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: moverick-mule-pre
      commit: $CI_COMMIT_SHA
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: moverick-mule-pre
        commit: $CI_COMMIT_SHA
```

Otherwise, you will get error like below

> The Deployment "moverick-mule-pre" is invalid:
>
> - spec.selector: Required value
> - spec.template.metadata.labels: Invalid value: map[string]string{...} `selector` does not match template `labels`

Comment: This is a helpful answer, thanks. Would you be so kind as to improve it with a reference to the appropriate documentation? E.g. from my own experimentation it appears that there is a default value to `selector`, and it looks like the default is something like `name: yourDeploymentConfigName`.

Comment: Up to apps.v1beta1, the selector was optional, but since apps.v1beta2 it is required and must match the labels, see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/. Even if using v1beta1 there is no point in not having it, because sooner or later you will have to upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

This might happen during one additional case wherein you have made changes to deployment labels and you're deploying through argocd. In this case Argocd sync would fail

The solution is to delete the deployment and recreate it. Since labels are immutable in Kubernetes

you can refer this: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50808

Answer (score 3):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-security-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend-security
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: # labels to select/identify the deployment
        app: backend-security
    spec:     # pod spec                  
      containers: 
      - name: backend-security
        image: yurifull/backend-security:v1.0.0 # image we pushed
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3001
```

this works for me...

Answer (score 0):

Just for someone coming across this, in my case trying to deploy (`kubectl apply -f`) resulted in the described error but there were some pods with status `ImagePullBackOff`, after removing these `kubectl apply` worked.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, app-revision is mismatched between *metadata.labels.app-revision* and *spec.template.metadata.labels.app-revision* this also could lead to this kind of error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).